# No results when using filters in Mongodb Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to do some basic filtering in MongoDB Compass, but I keep on getting no results. Here is an example without filtering

[image]

And this is with filtering

[image]

I've tried the following filters and neither of them work:

```
{"INSTALL_TYPE" : /.*vpos.*/}
{"DIVISION" : /.*20.*/}
{"DIVISION" : "20"}
```

However, in another table in the same database, search works fine.

[image]

Why am I getting no results when I try filtering in MongoDB Compass in this one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the strings having quotation marks in them. When exporting the tables from Oracle SQL, quotation marks were wrapping some of the values. When I then imported the CSV, the CSV which had all its values wrapped it quotes imported fine. However, when importing a CSV where only some of the values had quotes, it caused those entries to have quotes inside the string.

Purging all the CSV files of quotes, emptying the tables, and re importing the CSVs, made all the entries no longer have quotes. And now the filtering works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the *column names* containing quotes will cause Compass to behave as OP described.
If your CSV looks like this:

```
"INCIDENT_ID"
"2016376978"
```

Importing into Compass. Note the column header contains double-quotes therefore the filter doesn't produce results.
[image: column name includes double-quotes, filter results in 0 rows]

I didn't change any of my *values* as the accepted answer said. I only changed column headers, so my CSV looks like this:

```
INCIDENT_ID
"2016376978"
```

Now importing the collection means the column header will not have quotes, and the *same filter* as before will not produce results (even though values themselves contain double-quotes):
[image: column name does not contain double-quotes so a filter works]

**EDIT**

To clarify, you **may still want to remove double-quotes from your CSV *values* before importing**. In my case, removing double-quotes from *values* would've been convenient and closer to my expectations.

However, it's not *necessary* for Compass queries; the OP's original regex query would've returned results, if only their *column names* were stripped of quotes:
[image: regex queries will find results even if result values have double-quotes]